# Placing nodes along an ellipse in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

Is anybody aware of a simple way to place nodes at arbitrary positions along an ellipse?  Ideally I  would want to mimic notation like

```
\draw (0,0) ellipse [ x radius=2, y radius = 1] node[pos=.3] {Hi, I am a node.};
```

But this does not work. It is possible to splice together four curves that will do a good approximation, for instance

```
\node[coordinate,name=top] at (0,3) {};
\node[coordinate,name=bottom] at (0,-3) {};
\node[coordinate,name=left] at (-5,0) {};
\node[coordinate,name=right] at (5,0) {};

\draw (left) .. controls ($(left)+(0,2)$) and ($(top)-(2,0)$) .. (top);
\draw (left) .. controls ($(left)-(0,2)$) and ($(bottom)-(2,0)$) .. (bottom);
\draw (right) .. controls ($(right)+(0,2)$) and ($(top)+(2,0)$) .. (top);
\draw (right) .. controls ($(right)-(0,2)$) and ($(bottom)+(2,0)$) .. (bottom);
```

will give a decent approximation to

```
\draw (0,0) ellipse [ x radius=5, y radius = 3];
```

Using this method I can then use the notation I wanted to use.
But if I want to make several pictures with this method or make adjustments, then it can become a lot of work.  Also, the control points I picked were from guess and check as opposed to some other knowledge (this is a fault I know) so for varying sizes I will need to guess and check each time. So I am hoping for something a little more compact.

Comment: With the `arc` operation (Section 13.8 of the version 2.00 TikZ manual) you can easily draw parts of an ellipse.

Answer (score 40):

You can let TikZ calculate the position of the node for you:

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (2,0) ellipse (2 and 1);
    \node at ($(2,0)+(75:2 and 1)$) {a node};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The key here is that `(75:2 and 1)` is the position at 75 degrees on an ellipse with axis lengths 2 and 1 centered at (0,0). The (2,0) is just an example how you get an off-center position.

Comment: Awesome.  I did not realize that you could put an ellipse inside of the angular coordinates.  This fits perfectly for what I was thinking.

Answer (score 12):

One thing you could do is create an elliptical node and then use the anchor points of that node. So for example,

```
\node[draw,ellipse,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=4cm] (a) at (0,0) {};
\node[above right] at (a.75) {Hi I am a node};
```

Here `75` is the angle around the ellipse where you want the text node to be placed.

Answer (score 7):

With pgf 2.10 CVS !! You need to use `arc` operation because you need to know the path wih a point for the beginning and a point final. Idem for the circle.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
  arrows,
  calc
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

 \draw (8,0) arc [start angle=0,   
                  end angle=360,
                  x radius=2cm, 
                  y radius=4mm]
                                node [pos=0] {WITH} 
                                node [pos=.25] {CVS !!} 
                                node [pos=.5] {2.10}  
                                node [pos=.75] {PGF};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know if it is ever needed but adding `-- cycle` might be an option just to be on the safe side.

Comment: @percusse I don't know too but it's better to use it.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing but with a rotated ellipse? The attribute `rotate=45` does not work on arcs...