# Placing Nodes along an rotated ellipse in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

In relation to [this quesion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1793/placing-nodes-along-an-ellipse-in-tikz):

How can one place nodes along a rotated ellipse? ()

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. What do you mean by rotated ellipse? Kindly add the code you have tried so far.

Comment: An ellipse where the major axis is not in parallel to the x- or the y-axis. For code and graphical illustration in the unrotated case please take a loot at the linked question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not clear to me how your code will look like that draws a rotated ellipse. The code in the linked answer can be simply rotated as a whole by `\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=60]`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=60]
    \draw (2,0) ellipse (2 and 1);
    \node[draw,fill=blue,circle,text=white] at ($(2,0)+(75:2 and 1)$) {A};
    \node[draw,fill=red,circle,text=white] at ($(2,0)+(275:2 and 1)$) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the node contents to be rotated too, then use `transform shape` like  `\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=60,transform shape]` in the above code.

[image]

**To address the query in the comments:**

To hide the ellipse itself you may

1. comment out the entire line

   ```
   \draw (2,0) ellipse (2 and 1);
   ```
2. use `draw=none` as the option

   ```
   \path[draw=none] (2,0) ellipse (2 and 1);
   ```

Some sample code for fun:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=60]
\foreach \x/\y in {0/A,30/B,60/C,90/D,120/E,150/F,180/G,210/H,240/I,270/J,300/K,330/L}{
    \node[draw=none,minimum width=10pt,fill=blue!60!green!30,circle,text=white,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at ($(2,0)+(\x:2 and 1)$) {\y};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot; This will do the trick. How can i prevent the drawing of the ellipse? I don't want it to be visible; I just need the nodes to be at the corresponding coordinates.

Comment: @GarlefWegart Please see the edit.

Comment: Great answer; Thank you. Misfortunately I can't give you more then one +1 :)

Comment: @GarlefWegart: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use an arc to draw the ellipse, which allows you to place the nodes a specified distance along the border of the ellipse:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [rotate=30, x radius=2cm, y radius=1cm, delta angle=360] (0,0)
    arc [start angle=0]
    node [pos=0.13] {A}
    node [pos=0.75] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For this to work, one needs [the CVS version of TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38763/16595).