# Placing nodes along an ellipse with variables

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-calc, tikz-positioning

My question is almost exactly the same as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1793/226781): I would like to place a node along an ellipse, but using variables. I built a MWE based on the [best rated answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1805/226781):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border = 5mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node (origin) at (0, 2) {Origin};
    
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xradius{3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\yradius{1}
    \draw[thick] (origin) ellipse (\xradius cm and \yradius cm);
    
    \node[draw] (test) at ($ (origin) + (90:3 and 1) $) {Hello};
    \node[draw] (test2) at ($ (origin) + (90:\xradius and \yradius) $) {Hello}; % <--- This line is not working

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, I would like to use values stored in a variable instead of setting the value itself, something like: `($ (origin) + (90:\xradius and \yradius) $)`.

I am using Lualatex, so I am open to solutions with Lua, although I guess the solution will not require it

Comment: Do `(90:{\xradius} and \yradius)`.

Answer (score 1):

As answered in the comments by Qrrbrbirlbel, using curly braces around `\xradius` solve the problem: `(90:{\xradius} and \yradius)`